# How to make activity UI changes from an Android AsyncTask?

Tags: android, oop, android-asynctask

In a scenario where I have a UI that will be updated from a separate thread (using AsyncTask), I can define the AsyncTask as an inner class of the activity, but this has two downsides I find problematic:

1. It makes the source files very large, reducing efficiency in managing the code
2. It makes it hard to reuse the thread class

What's a good solution? Use an inner class, but abstract everything it does to other classes? Pass a reference to the Activity to the AsyncTask? Always define the AsyncTask class as an inner class and just accept source files will be large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few examples I have seen just pass a `Context` into the constructor of the `AsyncTask`.

```
public class BackgroundStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ...
    Context mContext;
    ...
    BackgroundStuff(Context context){
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    ...
}
```

I would be interested to hear if anyone else uses any other approaches.

Comment: Passing a context to the class is what I currently do, it seems rather messy, but maybe there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 13):

First and foremost: when using an `AsyncTask` you must not do UI activity within `doInBackground()`.

What you can do is - if you want to e.g. update status for a long running background job, is to `publishProgress(values)` from doInBackground(). 
The runtime will then for those values call your `onProgressUpdate(values)` callback, which runs in the UI thread and from where you can update the UI.

Have a look at e.g. https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java#L336 to see an example.

The AsyncTask can be implemented in an own class file.

Comment: The doInBackground() method can't access the UI, the framework throws an exception if it tries. But my question relates more to how the AsyncTask subclass actually accesses the UI.

Comment: @Olli this is what I say: doInBackgrround() must not access the UI. Either do it before or after with onPre|PostExecute() or in between by publishing the progress. Those three callback methods are allowed to access the UI

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat odd P.O.V with AsyncTasks because I generally prefer using normal Threads, but essentially the way I perform a background task and update a UI is create a Handler at the end of the onCreate() method, I'll then override the handleMessage(Message msg) method.

Then in my Thread, I'll pass the Handler in as a parameter, then when I wish to make an update I'll  send a message from the thread to the Handler, now what this does is communicate from the new background thread onto the UI thread to process work on the UI.

Now I imagine AsyncTasks perform a similar task but removes the need to implement override the Handlers' handleMessage method.

It'd be interesting learning more about any advantages / disadvantages between these two approaches.

Comment: I initially used Handler, but I just didn't gel with it, though that's an entirely subjective perception. I like the clarity of AsyncTask, and I usually break them out as separate classes (rather than an inner class) which helps me to work with it, and keep the Activity subclass more manageable.