# Progress Bar not updating in AsyncTask

Tags: android, progress

I'm trying to update the progress bar in a AsyncTask while downloading some stuff..
Here is the code:

```
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, Explanation.class);
    mContext.startActivity(myIntent);

    View inflater = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.explanation, null);
    mProgressDialog = (ProgressBar) inflater.findViewById(R.id.Explanation_ProgressBar);
    }

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);

}
```

xml:

```
  <ProgressBar 
   android:max="100"       
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/Explanation_ProgressBar" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>
```

A note: The progress bar is in the layout of the Activity I call in the onPreExecute(). and I want to update it through the AsyncTask. Is this possible? Why isnt it updated?

Comment: i think it might have to do how the ui elements are supposed to be modified on the main thread.

Comment: actually try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836716/how-to-make-activity-ui-changes-from-an-android-asynctask

Comment: Shouldnt the AsyncTask deal with all the threading stuff?

Comment: never mind my previous comments i read your question wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update progress dialog you need to call `publishProgress(...)` from `doInBackground`.
Check Usage and publishProgress sections of [AsyncTask doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

The doInBackground thread can not access the UI thread. The onProgressUpdate allows you to post updates to the UI thread. This is what your code should look like:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {       
    this.publishProgress(progress);
}   

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);

}
```