# Add a button dynamically in AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-button, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to add a `Button` dynamically in the `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask`. I'm doing this inside of an class that extends `Fragment`. I can use this code to dynamically create a `Button` outside of `AsyncTask`:

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        LinearLayout theLayout =  (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        Context mFragmentContext=getActivity().getApplicationContext(); 
        Button btn=new Button(mFragmentContext);
        btn.setText("Hello Button");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsd = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150,30);
        paramsd.height = paramsd.WRAP_CONTENT;
        paramsd.width = paramsd.WRAP_CONTENT;
        btn.setLayoutParams(paramsd);
        theLayout.addView(btn); 

        Button test = (Button)theLayout.findViewById(R.id.test41);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("response", "Button Clicked");
                new loadSomeStuff().execute();
                Intent log = new Intent();
                log.setClass(getActivity(), Assignment.class);
                startActivity(log);
            }
        });

        return theLayout;
    }

    // Method to load stuff using async task. Grabs information from URL and
    // calls read stream
    public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                int limit = 100;
                String accessToken = "";
                URL url = new URL( "SomeSite" + accessToken 
                            + "&status=active" + "&limit=" + limit);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                readStream(con.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute( String result )  {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Context mFragmentContext=getActivity().getApplicationContext(); 
            Button btn=new Button(mFragmentContext);
            btn.setText("Hello Button");
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsd = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150,30);
            paramsd.height = paramsd.WRAP_CONTENT;
            paramsd.width = paramsd.WRAP_CONTENT;
            btn.setLayoutParams(paramsd);
            //theLayout.addView(btn); 

            Log.v("response", "on post biatch");
        }
    }

    // Processes information from URL and prints it in format
    private void readStream(InputStream in) throws JSONException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line = reader.readLine();
            String total_results = new JSONObject(line).getJSONObject(
                "response").getString("total_results");
            int assignCount = Integer.parseInt(total_results.toString());
            Log.v("response", total_results);
            JSONObject data;

            for (int i = 0; i < assignCount; i++) {
                data = new JSONObject(line).getJSONObject("response");
                String id = data.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                String title = data.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                Log.v("response", title);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is, when I try to put this code in `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask`, `addview(btn)` line has errors because the `Layout` is not defined. I can't figure out how to pass the `Layout`. Is there some way to grab the activity's `Layout` with some kind of built in method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836716/how-to-make-activity-ui-changes-from-an-android-asynctask

Comment: if your `Async Task` is in same class you can make it public. In other case you can pass your `Layout` as a constructor of your `Async Task`

Comment: Please post all of your code.

Comment: Ok added all my code, I can't make theLayout public, it won't let me for some reason. Says I can only make it final. And that doesn't do anything

Comment: Since it's an inner-class, just use `Fragment's` `getView()` method.  It returns the same view returned in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add a Constructor to your `loadSomeStuff` class?  On the Constructor, pass the `View` that you want to add the `Button` to.

```
public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private View view;

    public loadSomeStuff(View v) {
        view = v;
    }

    public String doInBackground(String... strings) {
       //...
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //...
        view.addView(btn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Handler; add the following to the main`Activity`:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
        case 0:
            Context mFragmentContext=getActivity().getApplicationContext(); 
            Button btn=new Button(mFragmentContext);
            btn.setText("Hello Button");
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsd = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150,30);
            paramsd.height = paramsd.WRAP_CONTENT;
            paramsd.width = paramsd.WRAP_CONTENT;
            btn.setLayoutParams(paramsd);
            // addView(btn) in your LinearLayout
            break;  
        }
    }
};
```

Pass the `Handler` with `AsyncTask` costructor and in `onPostExecute(String result)` use the `Handler` as follows:

```
public void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 0;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

You can create different event in `Handler` class and select the kind with `msg.what`.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me to add a RelativeLayout programatically and putting a button inside it:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams yourlayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

yourlayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,anotherview.getId());
yourlayout.addView(yourbutton, yourlayout);
```

I strongly recommend you that you must use setId() and assign a unique id to every view if you work with dynamic layouts and not with static XML. This is needed to position a view using another views references.